# PHP - how to use a session in place of the GET var

Tags: php

I have a dilemma going on here. I need to use a session to navigate records in a foreach loop.

```
foreach($key as $val)
{
  echo '<tr><td><a href="'.$key.'">$val</a></td></tr>';
}
```

Ok, the $key in this equasion is my database key and when the user clicks the link, it will take them to the next page. This "next page" parses the data and places it into a query string for the URL. I don't like the way it's working with the query string and want to use a session to handle the $key instead but I dont know how to make that work for a hyperlink. Can someone please give me a hand?

Thanks

The whole thing in a nutshell is that I don't want to get the key off the URL. It has nothing to do with security but I want to put that key into a hidden field so that I can parse it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will hide the key and store it in session. You could also use numeric indexes instead of the md5 and salt if you dont like the long md5 strings, or the uniqid function.

```
//store this value in a config file
$salt = 'somelongsecretstring';

foreach($key as $val)
{
  $md5 = md5($salt . $key);
  $_SESSION['keys'][$md5] = $key;
  echo '<tr><td><a href="?key='.$md5.'">$val</a></td></tr>';
}
```

At the next page:

```
$md5 = $_GET['key'];
if (!isset($_SESSION['keys'][$md5])) {
    //key doesnt exists, redirect to previous page and display error.
}
$key = $_SESSION['keys'][$md5];
```

Comment: In fact... I can build my entire URL using this array / hash combo, Right?

Comment: I dont see where its usefull or smart to hide the entire url like this. Should generally just be used to hide the parts unique to each user you dont want in cleartext in the url.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. It was always my preference to hide as much of the query string as possible but in my case here, I really only need the db key for parsing in a form later on. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

That's no good idea. The URI (or URL if you want) identifies a UNIQUE resource. A short example:

**Good** (unique)
`http://example.org/page/1` => GET key = 1
`http://example.org/page/2` => GET key = 2

**Bad** (not unique)
`http://example.org/page` w/ session key = 1
`http://example.org/page` w/ session key = 2

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't follow this at all. My problem is not with uniqueness but with using a session instead of a GET variable. Could you explain a but more?

Comment: What I'm saying is that you should use the query string. Imagine you want to share a URL with someone else but he gets another result because of session usage. That's not what you want. :-)

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, all you need to do is add the `$key` to the current $_SESSION.

```
foreach ($key as $val){
   $_SESSION['key'] = $key;
   echo '<tr><td><a href="'.$key.'">$val</a></td></tr>';
}
```

Then, all you have to do is look for `$_SESSION['key']` when you want to use it again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Use the code button (0s and 1s) instead of <pre>, or just add 4 spaces to the start of each line.  Also did you mean to overwrite $_SESSION['key'] each time?

Comment: Hey evilness. Thanks for the help. So if I'm understanding you correctly, instead of using the $key, I will assign the key in the loop to a session. Will I then use the session in place of where I am using $key? I'm unclear as to how that will work though because the session will be an array at that point and how will I identify a unique row of data?

Comment: You do know this is a loop, and $_SESSION['key'] will only contain the last $key value?

Comment: I know but that is easily fixed. I'm after the logic here. :)

Comment: @Greg, @OIS - Oops. That's what happens when you answer at 2:30am.